# How to keep cloud storage synced when changing an operating system?

Tags: reinstall, cloud-storage

I have a folder with symlinks synced to a cloud storage and I'm switching a linux distro.

Is there a way to keep my data, which is on a separate /home partition that will not be formatted, synced on the fresh install without re-downloading everything?

Comment: Depends on how the sync was done initially. If it's rsync you should be good, many other synchronization systems use some method to create metadata so you only have to manage changed deferentially.

Comment: I'm confused. If it is on a separate partition and you wont format it, you surely don't need to sync since the data is already there? Also, which cloud storage?

Comment: @JulianKnight, the data *is* there, but would the client software "understand" that it's the same data when I'll install it? (copy.com)

Comment: You'll need to share which cloud storage provider it is. Basically, it is likely to depend on where the sync database is stored. This is most likely somewhere in your home folder!